Impact Parameter as function of orbital parameters
In the case of a binary system (pulsar+companion), the impact parameter $\textbf{b}$ is the projection of the binary separation $\textbf{r}$ on the sky plane:
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\textbf{b} = \textbf{n} \times \textbf{r} \times \textbf{n}
\end{equation}
where $\textbf{n}$ is the unit vector pointing from the center of mass of the binary system to the Earth, while $\textbf{r}$ is the position vector of the pulsar relative to its companion and corresponds to the binary separation. Its modulus is $r=|\textbf{r}|=a(1-e^2)/(1+e \cos\phi)$, where $a$ is the semi-major axis, $e$ the eccentricity and $\phi$ the true anomaly measured from periastron.
In a paper [1], I found that  $b=|\mathbf{b}|=r\sqrt{1-\sin^2{i}\sin^2{\psi}}$, where $i$ is the inclination of orbital plan w.r.t. the sky plane and $\psi=\phi+w$ is the true anomaly measured from ascending node.  I managed to get this result by using $\textbf{n}=(0,-\sin{i},-\cos{i})$ and $\textbf{r}=(r \cos \psi, r \sin \psi,0)$.
The problem is when one takes into account the motion of the companion, which changes the actual impact parameter, according to
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
\textbf{b} = \textbf{n} \times \textbf{r} \times \textbf{n} - \dfrac{r_{//}}{c}\textbf{n} \times \textbf{v}_{c} \times \textbf{n}
\end{equation}
where $r_{//}=r \sin{i} \sin{\psi} $ and $\textbf{v}_c$ is the companion's velocity. In the simple case of circular edge-on orbit ($e=0$ ; $i=\pi/2$), I found $b=r \cos{\psi} - r_{//}v_c \sin{\psi}$, while the correct result is $b=r \cos{\psi} - r_{//}v_c$, i.e. a factor of $\sin{\psi}$ less [1]. Why?

HINT
I used that $\textbf{n} \times \textbf{v}_{c} \times \textbf{n}= \textbf{v}_c (\textbf{n}\cdot \textbf{n})-\textbf{n}(\textbf{n} \cdot \textbf{v}_c)$, where $\textbf{n} \cdot \textbf{n}=1$ and $\textbf{v}_c= v_c( \sin{\psi}, -\cos{\psi},0)$, which is opposite to the pulsar's velocity.
